# python iterate over class variables and only get values of variables

Tags: python, iteration, enumeration

i want an enumerator class which has class variables with same values such as:

```
from enum import Enum
class Cars(Enum):
  BMW = "BMW"
  Mercedes = "Mercedes"
  Renault = "Renault"
```

Now i want to iterate over Cars class and get string values of each car as:

```
for car in Cars:
  print(car)
```

gives output:

```
Cars.BMW
Cars.Mercedes
Cars.Renault
```

to get only string values i need to do:

```
for car in Cars:
  print(car.value)
```

But i dont want iterate with`.value`

i tried to implement `__iter__()` and `__next__()` methods but couldn't achieve it.

Comment: It doesn't seem to me like it makes much sense to give enum members the same values as their names. You could simply set them all to [`auto()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.auto) and then get the name with `car.name`. Beyond that, I'm not sure what your question/objection is, exactly.

Comment: Write a custom `__repr__` function!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by overriding `__str__`:

```py
from enum import Enum


class Cars(Enum):
    BMW = "BMW"
    Audi = "Audi"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.value
```

This isn't really how enum's should be used, though, so I wouldn't recommend it. Just use the colors as the objects they are, and call on `.value` when you need it. Better yet you can just use `.name`:

```
from enum import auto, Enum


class Cars(Enum):
    BMW = auto()
    Audi = auto()


for brand in Cars:
    print(brand.name)
```

Comment: They were never explicit about that - besides, I gave them an alternative :)